# Re-write URL path before it appears to the user

Tags: uri, path-aliases, redirection

I have a node with path my-awesome-node. Whenever I am accessing that node I am redirecting to a fixed path via hook_preprocess_page().

As a next step I also want to overwrite the path in the browser to show my-awesome-node. I am doing this with javascript right now, but it is still visible to the user. Is there a way to achieve this via php?

Comment: So if somebody wants to visit (browse) that my-awesome-node, what should they enter as a path instead (to indicate that they want to visit that very same node? Something like some-other-path-to-that-awesome-node?

Comment: They can access it both ways. my-awesome-node and some-other-path-to-that-awesome-node will point to some-other-path-to-that-awesome-node(fixed).